# function next to a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

() => {} (); I don't know what that is.

```
(async () => {
   try {
      //await authentication
   } catch (error) {
      //catch errors
   }
})();
```

Can you do that? How does that even work? So this is a node.js piece of code where I'm learning how to attach a database to a node application and we're using sqlite along with async/await. To connect to the database, we're preparing to use the function above but I don't understand how you can even do it in javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE It's JS function that runs as soon as it is defined.

Comment: It’s an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (immediately invoked function expression). It defines a function and invokes it.

Comment: `(() => { code here })` defines an anonymous arrow function.  Adding the `()` on the end, calls it immediately without having to reference a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function abc = () => {

}
```

is a normal function in javascript, and to execute we need to add `()` before the function name similar to `abc();`

Now to make anonymous function we need to do `function () => {}` and to execute it we need to add `()`. So, execute it we wrap it inside `()` to make a block and add `()` at last to execute.

This will make syntax look lile :-

```
( () => {

})();
```

this is what we call an IIFE in javascript.

Now `async await`  is another concept in js , where we make a function `async` and  use  `await`  to make a function wait to resolve before continuing execution.

So, now our code will look like :-

```
(async() => {
   try{
     await authenticate();
   }catch(){

   }
})();
```